# The localNotification is not working well. The function didReceiveLocalNotification is not called at the good moment

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I created a localNotification to launch a message and it is not called at the good moment. What is strange is that when I put a date in the future, it never fire it, but if I put a date in the past, it fire it at the launch of the app...

Main function :

```
...
 NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents new];
    [comps setDay:28];
    [comps setMonth:02];
    [comps setYear:2017];
    [comps setHour:16];
    [comps setMinute:50];
    [comps setSecond:00];

    NSDate *alarmDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    // or @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a" if you prefer the time with AM/PM

    NSDate *currentDate= [NSDate date];
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    // Set the fire date/time
    [localNotification setFireDate:alarmDate];
    [localNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];

    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;

    // Setup alert notification
    [localNotification setAlertAction:@"Open App"];
    // [localNotification setAlertBody:[randonQuotesDic objectForKey:@"Rajneesh"]];
    [localNotification setAlertBody:@"You had set a Local Notification on this time"];

    localNotification.soundName=UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [localNotification setHasAction:YES];
    UIApplication *app=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
...
```

Function receive local notification :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    // check state here

    if(state ==UIApplicationStateBackground ){

    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wake" message:notification.alertBody delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertView show];
    });
}
```

It doesn't work correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer :

You have to simply authorise it. You have to put that lines just before initialize the localNotification in you main function :

```
 UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
    UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
```